# $f,g,h\in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $f,g,h\in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be three functions.

I have the following three sets:

$S_{1}=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\,:\,f(n)\neq g(n)\}$

$S_{2}=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\,:\,g(n)\neq h(n)\}$

$S_{3}=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\,:\,f(n)\neq h(n)\}$

Part of proving a theorem, I need to prove that for every $f,g,h\in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, if $S_{1}$ is finite and $S_{2}$ is finite then also $S_{3}$ is finite. I can't figure how to start to prove it.

Comment: what is the mean of "final"?

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo Later in the question he says "finite". I think it is a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
(\mathbb{N}\setminus S_1)\cap(\mathbb{N}\setminus S_2)\subseteq \mathbb{N}\setminus S_3
$$
Then,
$$
S_3\subseteq S_1\cup S_2.
$$

Comment: Specifically, $S_3$ is the symmetric difference of $S_1$ and $S_2$, but that detail isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $n\in S_3\setminus S_1$ implies $f(n)\neq h(n)$ and $f(n)= g(n)$, which implies $h(n)\neq g(n)$, or that $n\in S_2$. So $S_3\setminus S_1\subseteq S_2$ and hence finite.

Similarly $S_3\setminus S_2\subseteq S_1$, also finite.

Now try to prove by similar reasonings $S_3\cap S_1\subseteq S_3\setminus S_2$, and $S_3\cap S_2\subseteq S_3\setminus S_1$.

Also note that the three relations $f(n)\neq g(n)$, $g(n)\neq h(n)$ and $h(n)\neq f(n)$ cannot be true simultaneously, implying $S_1\cap S_2\cap S_3=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $S_1$ is finite, and $S_2$ is finite.  So they each have maximum elements.  Let $m$ be a finite natural number that is larger than the maximum of either.

For any $k \ge m$ then $k \ge m> \max S_1$ so $k \not \in S_1$ so $f(k) = g(k)$.  Likewise $k \ge m > \max S_2$ so $k \not \in S_2$ so $g(k) = h(k)$.  So $f(k) = h(k)$ and $k \not \in S_3$.

So the only way for $k \in S_3$ is for $k < m$.  There are at most a finite number of such elements in $S_3$.

In other words:

If $k > \max S_1$ then $f(k) = g(k)$.   If $k > \max S_2$ then $g(k) = h(k)$.  So if $k > \max(\max S_1, \max S_2)$ then $f(k)=g(k)=h(k)$ and $k\not \in S_3$.  So if $k \in S_3 \implies k \le \max(\max S_1, S_2)$.  So $S_3$ is finite.